# Identify visible images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got about 120 images (icons). When the page loads, a random number of images will be visible. I need to pass the id of each visible image one at a time to a function. How can I do this?

```
<img src="fruits/lychee.png" class ="fruit" id="fruitl156">
<img src="fruits/cranberry.png" class ="fruit" id="fruitl141">
<img src="fruits/avocado.png" class ="fruit" id="fruitl214">
```

```
$('#getIDs').click(function(){
   if( $('.fruit').css('visibility', 'visible') ){
       var thisid = $(this).attr("id");
       passFunction( thisid, var2, var3 );
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get each visible element and pass it to function.

```
$('.fruit:visible').each(function(){
    var thisid = this.id;
    passFunction( thisid, var2, var3 );
})
```

Another way you can get array of IDs using `.map()` and `get()`, then pass it all at once, and do the necessary in the called function.

```
var IDs = $('.fruit:visible').map(function () {
    return this.id;
}).get();

passFunction( IDs, var2, var3 );//Changes on passFunction are needed for handling array.
```

Comment: Or like you mentioned in one of  the comments, you can make an array and then send using `.get()`

Comment: Thanks for that comment. Could you show how it's done using `.get()`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**:visible**](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) pseudo-selector to select only visible elements. Also, as you're having multiple elements, you need to use `each` to loop over them.

```
$('#getIDs').click(function () {
    $('.fruit:visible').each(function () {
    //       ^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^
        var thisid = $(this).attr("id");
        passFunction(thisid, var2, var3);
    });
});
```

You can also use `is` to check if the element is visible

```
$('#getIDs').click(function () {
    $('.fruit').each(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
            var thisid = $(this).attr("id");
            passFunction(thisid, var2, var3);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. WHat about `.map()`, `each()` will those be better options because there are many ids to be passed?

Comment: Thanks. Since there are many id's to pass what would be best performance wise?

Comment: @Bekki Selecting only `visible` images, as in the first code in the answer will be better

Comment: @Bekki If you add complete code of `passFn`, I might help you optimize your code